What ESC matches criteria?
Is there any ESC, that takes PWM from an Arduino as an input, has three wires for three motor phases and has three wires for the hall effect sensors? Does this match my criteria Product ?

I suspect that there may be. The trick on this site is to ask a pointed question that can produce a useful answer.

I looked through amazon, but I don't understand how to know what the wires are used for. Is there always one wire to connect to the power supply and one ground wire? Maybe this could fill my criteria, but I don't know

Just looking at the photo, I see three wires for the 3-phase motor (A, B, C), three for the PWM signal input (receiver) and two for the battery (+ and -).

There are no Hall sensor inputs on this ESC; it's designed for sensorless motor control.
The BEC (Battery Elimination Circuit) normally has an power output derived from the battery (from the markings, 5V at up to 3A for this unit) on the thin red and black wires and the signal wire is the white wire

I have a question: Why is there sometimes a button on these ESCs? https://www.ebay.de/itm/394850688006?chn=ps&_ul=DE&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1dCP4Wck4TFOlhJEHzZfqAw70&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=707-134425-41852-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=394850688006&targetid=1716911581399&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9043806&poi=&campaignid=17943303986&mkgroupid=140642150118&rlsatarget=pla-1716911581399&abcId=9301060&merchantid=614946724&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw_LOwBhBFEiwAmSEQAUiiAVl4Dd0ZlT-k9iHn1Dk4p0IRK8buut6mbYbS0FQcD7tkI7k9ahoCF8AQAvD_BwE.

Looks like it's intended as an on/off switch but it may be programmable function. There is open-source firmware for some of the ESCs. The rabbit hole goes deep. I recall some good sources from the Applied Science YouTube channel- Ben made a DIY photoresist spincoater and dug into the subject.
